# unable to access math_expression package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to build a simple calculator app in flutter. I tried adding math_expression package to my dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file but I keep getting a "socket error trying to find package math_expression at https://pub.dev".

I tried math_expressions too but I keep getting the same error.

Inside my project folder, in the terminal, I tried running dart pub run math_expressions:interpreter (as instructed in dart dev) but I got an error that my pubspec.yalm file is not found

Comment: try copy pasting it direclty in yaml file from pub.dev, like here, math_expressions: ^2.4.0